# Receiver type X for for instance message is a forward declaration but header for class X is imported

Tags: objective-c, import, compiler-errors

I am trying to fix this compiler error:

> Receiver type X for for instance message is a forward declaration.

The App is a Universal iOS app with a storyboard. This problem involves three VC Classes.

From my `RootTableViewController`, the app can segue to either `InfoScaledViewController` or `SubListViewController`.
Compilation fails because of the following error.

> RootTableViewController.m:309:10: Receiver type 'InfoScaledViewController' for instance message is a forward declaration

There is no corresponding error a few lines above it, where identical procedure is done with `SubListViewController`.

These two lines are:

```
SubListViewController *destCntrlr = 
 (SubListViewController   *)segue.destinationViewController;
```

and

```
InfoScaledViewController *destCntrlr = 
 (InfoScaledViewController *)segue.destinationViewController ;
```

If I comment out the line that causes this compilation error and set a breakpoint at that position, you can see from the following screenshot, why I am puzzled by the error.

[image]

As you can see, I have used `#import "InfoScaledViewController.h"` in RootTableViewController.m and `@class InfoScaledViewController` 
in RootTableViewController.h

I have read many answers given to address this error. None of the have helped.

File: InfoScaledViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BNRDynamicTypeManagedLabel.h"
    ...

@interface InfoScaledViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>  {

    BOOL pushedForImport;
    ...
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL pushedForImport;
    ...
@end //InfoScaledViewController.h
```

File: InfoScaledViewController.m

```
#import "InfoScaledViewController.h"
    ...

@implementation InfoScaledViewController

@synthesize  pushedForImport;

@end // InfoScaledViewController.m
```

File: SubListViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SubListViewController :  CoreDataTVC  < UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UIAlertViewDelegate, AddRecipeDelegate,EditRecipeDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate> {
    //...
    BOOL isNewPush;
}
    //...
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL isNewPush;
    //...
@end //SubListViewController.h
```

File: SubListViewController.m

```
#import "SubListViewController.h"
     //...
@implementation SubListViewController
    //...
@synthesize isNewPush;

@end
```

File:  RootTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 ...
// #import "InfoScaledViewController.h"
@class InfoScaledViewController;
@class SubListViewController;
   //...

@interface RootTableViewController : CoreDataTVC
< NameViewDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate,    UITableViewDataSource,  UITableViewDelegate  >
{
   //...
    SubListViewController *subListViewController;
    InfoScaledViewController* infoViewController;
   //...
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) SubListViewController *subListViewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) InfoScaledViewController * infoViewController;
    ...
@end
```

File: RootTableViewController.m

```
#import "RootTableViewController.h"
    //...
#import "SubListViewController.h"
#import "InfoScaledViewController.h"
    //...
@implementation RootTableViewController

@synthesize subListViewController = _subListViewController;
@synthesize infoViewController = _infoViewController;

    //...
@end // RootTableViewController.m
```

THE PLACE in RootTableViewController.m  WHERE ERROR OCCURS IS BELOW
Note: Xcode "recognizes" both SubListViewController and InfoScaledViewController Classes, giving both names the same color.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SLVC"]) {
        SubListViewController *destCntrlr 
            = (SubListViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        [destCntrlr setIsNewPush:YES];      //          NO ERROR HERE
        ...
    }else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"INFO"]){
        InfoScaledViewController *destCntrlr
           = (InfoScaledViewController *)segue.destinationViewController ;
        [destCntrlr setPushedForImport:(sender == nil) ? YES : NO];   // ERROR HERE breakpoint is here
            ...
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ADDCATEGORY"]){ 
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to import `SubListViewController.h` and `InfoScaledViewController.h` in `RootTableViewController.m`.

Comment: Also, when you declare a property, you don't also need to declare ivars nor do you need to `@synthesize` those ivars. All of that is taken care of when you declare the property. That doesn't have anything to do with your problem, it's just best practice for writing modern Objective-C.

Comment: @AdamPro13 It says in his code for `RootTableViewController.m` that he has imported those files. Which is odd, since I agree that that should solve the problem.

Comment: It looks to me that he's showing it commented out. Did you try cleaning the project?

Comment: None of the #import lines are commented except the third line of RootTableViewController.h. Thanks so much for reading. The central question in my mind is How can the app run through up to the  // ERROR HERE line, and know that destCntrlr is an instance of InfoScaledViewController -- while the line just after it (The ERROR HERE line) causes a compile error?